# Library for Video Filtering / Processing

Tags: video, filtering

I'm looking for a video processing / filtering library.

Does anyone know of a good project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libavcodec from project [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)